# Find value inside string

Tags: c#, string

I need to find values inside this string:

```
10days25hours15minutes
```

I need get the numbers of days, hours and minutes, but the string can change, like this:

```
10d25h15m
```

Comment: Are they always in the same order? (i.e. days, hours and minutes)

Comment: will it always be in the format of 10(day spearator)25(hours separator)15(mins separator) ? If sou you voudl do a regex replace on letters to some delimiter (and another to turn multiple delimeters into one) and then split on that delimter? Alternatively you could do a regex match on numbers and use the groups to get the individual amounts.

Comment: You'll need some spec for this, just 2 examples doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the input string consists of three decimal numbers each terminated by one or more non-digits, you can use the following regular expression:

```
var match = Regex.Match("10days25hours15minutes", @"(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+");

var result = new TimeSpan(
    days: int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value),
    hours: int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value),
    minutes: int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value),
    seconds: 0);

// result == {11.01:15:00}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [this](http://regexr.com?2va7n) regex:

```
(?<days>\d+)d\D*(?<hours>\d+)h\D*(?<minutes>\d+)m\D*
```

which matches
`10days25hours15minutes` and `10d25h15m`. (and also others)

You may want to make it more accurate according to your needs.

Example code:

```
var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("10days25hours15minutes", @"(?<days>\d+)d\D*(?<hours>\d+)h\D*(?<minutes>\d+)m\D*", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Days: {0} Hours: {1} Minutes: {2}", match.Groups["days"], match.Groups["hours"], match.Groups["minutes"]);
}
```

Comment: @soamazing `Days: 10 Hours: 25 Minutes: 15` is exactly the output I get when I run the sample code (`Mono 2.10.6`). Actually in initial answer I wrote `System.Text.Regex` instead of `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` and I fixed it a few seconds ago but that's not related to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Match(str, @"(?<days>[0-9]+)(d|days)
                   (?<hours>[0-9]+)(h|hours)
                   (?<minutes>[0-9]+)(m|minutes)");
```

Then retrieve the values using `match.Groups["days"].Value`, `match.Groups["hours"].Value`, `match.Groups["minutes"].Value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Text.Split(new string[]
    {"days", "hours", "minutes"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Or

```
Text.Split(new string[]{"d", "h", "m"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

return your number ordinaly...